# Transform a std::multimap into std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have a function written using `std::multimap` which is excruciatingly slow precisely because of the `std::multimap`. After analysis, I realized that I am only using the `std::multimap` as a *heap*, so I am trying to substitute it with a `std::priority_queue` which only allows for heap operations, in the hope it will be faster for this usage.

Of course, the element type of `std::priority_queue` would need to be `std::pair<mmKey, mmValue>`, and then I would pass a custom comparator to the `std::priority_queue` comparing only by the first values in the pair (which was the actual key for the `std::multimap`).

As everything is quite templated, I .. got quite lost and need help. I made an example code:

**The example with `std::multimap`**

```
template <typename Compare>
void littleTestFunction(Compare comp){
    std::multimap<int,int,Compare> testMap(comp);

    testMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,5));
    testMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,6));
    testMap.insert(std::make_pair(2,7));

    for (; !testMap.empty(); ){
        std::cout << testMap.begin()->second << std::endl;
        testMap.erase(testMap.begin());
    }
    return;
}

int main(void){
    littleTestFunction(std::less<int>());
}
```

**My attempt of transforming the `std::multimap` to `std::priority_queue`**

```
template <typename Compare>
class pqcomparison{
    private:
        Compare myComp;
    public:
        pqcomparison(Compare &cmp){
            myComp = cmp;
        }
        bool operator() (const std::pair<int, int> &lhs,
                         const std::pair<int, int> &rhs){
            return myComp(rhs.first, lhs.first);
        }
};

template <typename Compare>
void littleTestFunction(Compare comp){
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>,
                        std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >,
                        pqcomparison<Compare> >
                            mypq(pqcomparison<Compare>(comp));

    mypq.push(std::make_pair(1,5));
    mypq.push(std::make_pair(1,6));
    mypq.push(std::make_pair(2,7));

    for (; !mypq.empty(); ){
        std::cout << mypq.top().second << std::endl;
        mypq.pop();
    }
    return;
}
```

When I compile just the `std::priority_queue` declaration, I don't get any errors. But, when I try and compile the whole function, I get error messages regarding all the member functions of `std::priority_queue`.

Could somebody please suggest a solution?

Comment: I would like to ask why std::multimap is slower than std::priority_queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite well masked [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) case. Just change this line 
`std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>,
                        std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >,
                        pqcomparison<Compare> >
                            mypq(pqcomparison<Compare>(comp));`

to:
`std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>,
                        std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >,
                        pqcomparison<Compare> >
                            mypq{pqcomparison<Compare>(comp)};`

Notice that I have changed `()` with `{}`. In case when you are not using C++11 you should just put extra parenthesis, i.e. make it `mypq((pqcomparison<Compare>(comp)))`

Comment: I had to copy the code into MSDEV to see the difference! :-) Perhaps you could add a note to make it more obvious?

Comment: @Stefan I guess you're right, updated my answer a little for more clarity

Comment: @magor Thank you so much! I can't believe I've fallen for the most vexing parse _again_ ... I know about it, but here I just couldn't see it.